# How to make image centerInParent in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Facing some difficulties in flutter as I am new to it, how to centerInParent for imageView for flutter? The image is not center, I had use Align but still not working. And how to construct the image and text like this photo ?

```
  appBar: PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45.0),
      child: AppBar(
        leading: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {/* open left menu */},
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_title_menu.png", width: 18.0, height: 18.0,)),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        title: Container(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {/* open search */},
            child: Image.asset("assets/images/ic_title_search.png", width: 18.0, height: 18.0,)),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: Container(
              child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Image.network(""),)
              ],),
            ),
          )
        ],
        titleSpacing: 0.0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I hope this is something you wanted!**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color kRed = Colors.red;

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: kRed,
                  size: 30,
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: kRed,
                  size: 30,
                )
              ],
            ),
            Text(
              'Test Text',
              style: TextStyle(color: kRed, fontSize: 30),
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'Test Text',
                      style: TextStyle(color: kRed, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Test Text',
                      style: TextStyle(color: kRed, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                  color: kRed,
                  size: 30,
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Expected Output]

Just replace the Text Widget in the middle with Image Widget. And tweak with your colors.

Comment: The title property has a specific space, you could use up only within the space, if you want to add more in the leading, creating a row inside the AppBar works.

Comment: And you can use `padding: EdgeInsets.all(14.0)`

Answer (score 0):

App Bar has a property called centerTitle, it will add title on the Appbar center.

```
 centerTitle: true,
```

Comment: need to have layout similar to top image

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
 flexibleSpace: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
          child: Center(
              child: Image(
            image: AssetImage('assets/img/icon_1.png'),
 ))),
```